# Updating all values in table in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a Django model

```
class Hnap(models.Model):
    name=models.TextField(default='USD')
    value=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=5, default=0)
```

The content of the table is of the form

```
ID   name    value
1    USD     23.44
2    GBP     53.12
```

My View is

```
def hnap(request):
try:
    currency = Hnap.objects.all()
           

    if request.method == "POST":
        post_values = request.POST.copy()


except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
context = {
    'currency': currency,
    'errors': errors,
}
return render(request, 'hnap.html', context)
```

My template displays the name and puts the values in a textbox and assigns the name curr_(value of the index)

```
<form action="{% url  'hnap' %}" method="POST">
{% for i in currency %}
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col">{{i.name}}</div>
 <div class="col "><input type="text" class="form-control" name="curr_{{i.id}}" required value="{{i.value}}"></div>
 </div>
{% endfor %}
</form>
```

How do I write the view so that all the values in the text input are updated at one go?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
currency = request.POST.get["currency"]
currency_obj_list = [
    Hnap.objects.get(id=i['name'].lstrip('curr_')) for i in currency
]
for cur, currency_object in zip(currency, currency_obj_list):
    currency_object.value = cur["value"]
Hnap.objects.bulk_update(currency_obj_list, ['value'])
```

Comment: i guess the for loop inside the currency_obj_list is a mistake. After removing it, django gives the error 'method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: My bad. It was a typo. Updating it.